# Expressão regular (regex) para links em páginas web usando Python

Tags: python, regex

Estou tentando aprender a criar um webcrawler. Parte do código será para extrair links em uma página web (links que comecem por http ou https):

```
import re   
urls = re.findall(r'href=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)', s)
```

Como posso modificar ou criar uma nova rgex que apenas pegue links que comecem por http ou https? Não quero guardar a palavra "href" apenas "http://..." ou "https://..."
Não servem, por exemplo: "media/teste", "g1/noticia"

```
padrao = re.findall(r'href=[\'"]https?://[\w:/\.\'"_]+' ,html)
```

padrao também não ficou 100% funcional:

http://g1.globo.com/rio

http://g1.globo.com/"

Sairam alguns com " no final, o que não era para ocorrer!

Comment: Qual é o python que está a usar? 2 ou 3?

Comment: Uso python 3.4 mas também tenho python 2.7 instalado BackBox Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import urllib, re

url = "http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/143677"
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()

urls = re.findall('(?<=href=["\'])https?://.+?(?=["\'])', html)

for url in urls:
    print url
```

A expressão regular vai corresponder a tudo que estiver entre `href="` e `"` e que seja `http` ou `https`.

Você também pode fazer uso de um *parser* para isso, por exemplo o [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
import urllib, re
# Para a versao 4.x use from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/143677"
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
urls = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^https?://")})

for tag in urls:
    print tag['href']
```

Comment: Não precisa colocar r antes de '(?<=href=["\'])https?://.+?(?=["\'])' ? para ser raw string?

Comment: @EdS Sim, eu tinha esquecido de colocar. Veja se a primeira opção com *regex* faz o que você quer, pois eu não cheguei a testar ela em outras páginas.

Comment: Obrigado. Vou testar e te retorno!

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Para completar a excelente resposta do @zekk, aqui fica uma solução para python 3.x:

```
import requests, re

url = "http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/143677"
html = requests.get(url).text

urls = re.findall('(?<=href=["\'])https?://.+?(?=["\'])', html)
print(urls)
```